# today and not last 24 hours?

Tags: php, date

i my php codes i do time()-86400 to fetch everything from the last 24 hours, but how i can get everything today or everything from yesterday. thus it is no longer 86400 seconds, it should be after 12 midnight till current time.

hope this makes sense.. but how i can do this?

Comment: not another datetime question please. Is [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) that hard to understand? Is searching through the hundreds of other questions basically asking the same that difficult? And why is there still some people using arithmetics to calculate time when they dont account for any DST?

Comment: You'll probably have to use [localtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php) to break out the time value into components then [mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to reassemble it with time = midnight

Comment: how are you fetching? If its a query then you can just check the date, and not the time.

Comment: @Gordon:  How else are people going to accumulate reputation points if they can't answer the same PHP or Java question over and over again?

Comment: @Gilbert by answering the other answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()-strtotime('today')` -    difference between now and midnight;    `time()-strtotime('yesterday')` -    difference between now and yesterday    midnight; `time()-strtotime('-2    days')`...

for yesterday only (range $min to $max)

```
$start = strtotime('yesterday')
$end = strtotime('today') - 1;
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are "fetching" from a database, why not do it in the query?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = '2011-03-28';
```

If you are storing the date as a unix timestamp:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) = '2011-03-28';
```

Comment: and dat is saved as int? as in time()

Comment: it is a nice way via mysql, but i am using external database server. thus it is better to use only php to get time.

Answer (score 0):

Following will give you the seconds passed since January 1, 1970. Every object with a timestamp higher than this value is from the current day (given that you have set your timezones and local time correctly).

```
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP `date` and `strtotime` function in order to pick a day from now and retrieve the seconds that specific date. For more info, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gordon here - there are so many date/time examples. But hey, let's go over it again - assuming today begins at midnight, you use:

$start = strtotime('today');

Assuming "today" ends at 23:59, simple arithmetics imply that if you increment the $start by 24 hours and take away 1 second - you'll reach the end of today.

So:

```
$start = strtotime('today');
$end = $start + (3600 * 24) - 1;
```

Comment: simple arithmetics dont take DST into account.

Comment: Except people always go to the procedural functions, this is going to mess up with DST.

Comment: "today" part of strtotime ensures we're at the right day, if you believe this code will mess up DST (which occurs at 3 in the morning), feel free to point out how the 24 hour window of the current day would be messed up. Note, example was only for the today's day, not "yesterday" or the like.

Comment: @Michael the problem with arithmetics is that once they did that once, they will use it all the time instead of using the proper APIs PHP offers for that purpose.

Comment: Also: `$start = strtotime('2008-10-26'); $end = $start + 3600 * 24 - 1; echo date('c', $end), PHP_EOL;` will result in `2008-10-26T22:59:59+01:00`.

Comment: @Michael: Assume then that your code ran last sunday when DST went into effect. $end would have been 2011-03-28 00:59:59, an hour off (because last Sunday had only 23 hours instead of 24)

Comment: Yup, you're both correct, I'll make the changes to the example so DST is in effect.